# Peewee x Dash: DB connections aren't reused when called inside a Dash callback function

Tags: python, plotly-dash, peewee

I'm noticing that within a Plotly Dash app that uses a DB managed by Peewee, I'm getting `playhouse.pool.MaxConnectionsExceeded: Exceeded maximum connections.`, which is visible here:

```sql
ariobot=# SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity where client_port > 0 and application_name = 'test 1';
 count 
-------
    21
(1 row)

ariobot=#
```

This is the code that presents this behaviour:

```py
# test1.py

from peewee import Model, TextField
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase

db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(
    "postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/ariobot", autoconnect=True, application_name='test 1'
)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Test(BaseModel):
    test = TextField()

db.create_tables([Test])



from dash import register_page, dash_table, callback, dcc, Input, Output, html, Dash

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(id="value"),
        dcc.Interval(id="db_query_interval", interval=10000, n_intervals=0),
    ]
)

@callback(
    Output("value", "children"),
    Input("db_query_interval", "n_intervals"),
    )
def do_stuff(interval):
    db = Test.select()
    for db in db:
        val = db.test
    return val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This `test2.py` re-uses the same connection on each iteration of the loop, which is how I would have expected Dash to work:

```py
# test2.py

from peewee import Model, TextField
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase

db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(
    "postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/ariobot", autoconnect=True, application_name='test 2'
)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Test(BaseModel):
    test = TextField()

db.create_tables([Test])

from time import sleep

while True:
    db = Test.select()
    for db in db:
        val = db.test
    print(val)
    sleep(1)
```

```sql
ariobot=# SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity where client_port > 0 and application_name = 'test 2';
 count 
-------
     2
(1 row)

ariobot=#
```

Why is the connection not getting re-used in the `test1.py` case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how "Dash" is configured to run. Does it spawn a new thread to handle each request? If so that would explain the leaking connections (peewee uses a connection-per-thread by default).

My suggestion would be to find the relevant Dash documentation on adding pre- and post-request callbacks to open and close your connections. With flask, for example, you would just add:

```
# This hook ensures that a connection is opened to handle any queries
# generated by the request.
@app.before_request
def _db_connect():
    database.connect()

# This hook ensures that the connection is closed when we've finished
# processing the request.
@app.teardown_request
def _db_close(exc):
    if not database.is_closed():
        database.close()
```

Whether or not you use a connection pool, it is very important to call `db.close()` when you're done working with the connection. With the pool, especially, this is necessary for the conn to be returned to the pool and reused.

From a quick google it looks like you may be able to accomplish this with "Dash" via:

```
@app.server.before_request
...

@app.server.teardown_request
...
```

As usual, the peewee docs describe Peewee's connection management: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#connection-management